# What's the difference between Tags and Workspaces in awesome?

Tags: ubuntu, awesome-wm

I'm trying out awesome window manager, and I'm still not getting the hang of it. I don't quite understand the difference between tags and workspaces. I would appreciate a good explanation of how tags work.

Comment: Describe what you think is a workspace in awesome. AFAICT, tags *are* workspaces here. They're just called tags to perhaps better convey the nature of their operation, as in one tag has multiple windows, but it's also possible to tag a window with multiple tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags are a superset of workspaces. Workspaces are a subset of tags. Each client (window) has an associated list of tags, so you can display it in multiple "workspaces".

From the [documentation](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/manpages/awesome.1.html) : *"Windows are grouped by tags in awesome. Each window can be tagged with one or more tags. Selecting certain tags displays all windows with these tags."*

You have three clients, Firefox, Spotify, and Terminal. Firefox lists tag 1, Spotify lists tag 2, and Terminal lists tags 1 and 2. So when you are on tag 1, Firefox and Terminal are displayed. If you switch to tag 2, Spotify and Terminal are displayed. That's the same thing as workspaces, but you can display a client on multiple tags. You can even display several tags at the same time, so in this case, you'd have Firefox, Spotify and Terminal displayed at the same time.

Hope that helps, have fun with Awesome !

Comment: I would go so far as to say workspace is an obsolete concept. You can use tags to emulate workspaces by limiting the way you use them. :)